# How do I access the children of an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

If i have a component derived from `ItemsControl`, can I access a collection of it's children so that I can loop through them to perform certain actions?  I can't seem to find any easy way at the moment.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A solution similar to [Seb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1000438/3195477) but probably with better performance :

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
{
    UIElement uiElement =
        (UIElement)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
}
```

Comment: it seems if the control hasn't rendered/been shown yet, it won't have any items.

Answer (score 26):

See if this helps you out:

```
foreach(var item in itemsControl.Items)
{
    UIElement uiElement =
        (UIElement)itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

There is a difference between logical items in a control and an `UIElement`.

Answer (score 23):

To identify `ItemsControl`'s databound child controls (like a `ToggleButton`), you can use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < yourItemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
{

    ContentPresenter c = (ContentPresenter)yourItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(yourItemsControl.Items[i]);
    ToggleButton tb = c.ContentTemplate.FindName("btnYourButtonName", c) as ToggleButton;

    if (tb.IsChecked.Value)
    {
        //do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `c.ApplyTemplate();` before calling `FindName()` or else it returns null.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Anyway the c variable must be checked because it can be null, for example if the control is not visible.