# Retrieving children of ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the above XAML code, I am getting children (of ItemsCotnrol x:Name="PointsList) using below code and getting the count = 0. Can you help me to fix this issue.

```
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(pointsList);
        if (count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(pointsList, i) as UIElement;
                if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                {
                    textPoints = child as TextBlock;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

pointsList is defined as follows.

```
pointsList = (ItemsControl)GetTemplateChild("PointsList");
```

Comment: It is not a good practise to work with ItemsControl's content using trees. So what do you want to do with TextBoxes?

Comment: I want to capture mouse events for the TextBlock. Is there a way? Please let me know.

Comment: Just hook the mouse events at the ItemsControl level and let the events bubble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the children of an ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000345/how-do-i-access-the-children-of-an-itemscontrol)

Answer (score 4):

As you are using *myPoints* in your code behind you can use [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) *GetContainerForItem*. Just pass one of yours items to get container for it.

Code for getting textblock for each item with helper method *GetChild*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PointsList.Items.Count; i++)
{
     // Note this part is only working for controls where all items are loaded  
     // and generated. You can check that with ItemContainerGenerator.Status
     // If you are planning to use VirtualizingStackPanel make sure this 
     // part of code will be only executed on generated items.
     var container = PointsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
     TextBlock t = GetChild<TextBlock>(container);
}
```

Method for getting child object from DependencyObject:

```
public T GetChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject child = null;
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
         child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
         if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))
         {
             break;
         }
         else if (child != null)
         {
             child = GetChild<T>(child);
             if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))
             {
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     return child as T;
 }
```

Comment: @baalazamon, thanks, always forget the "..ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i)"