# Not able to refer a control in code behind in VS 2008 with WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I don't know why but for some reason I am not able to refer to my tbText control in my code behind file. Here is the XAML part:

```
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ic">

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>                                                

                     **<TextBlock x:Name="tbText"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="10" />**
                     <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill">

                    </Image>                                                  


                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I cannot refer to the "tbText" control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't refer to it because it is inside an Items control.

You'd have to search the ItemsControl children in order to find the textbox.

See [Finding control within wpf items control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980120/finding-control-within-wpf-itemscontrol) for ways to do this.