# Programmatically reference items rendered by ItemsControl from code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, code-behind

I have a Silverlight user control that contains an `ItemsControl` that renders a `StackPanel` containing another user control for each item in the data source, the XAML is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="ValuesItemSource">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel x:Name="ValuesPanel" Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:MyCustomControl DataContext="{Binding}"  x:Name="Value" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

How would I reference the collection of `MyCustomControls` (**Value**s) in the code behind of this user control?

(I have an event handler registered in the code behind of this control and I want to invoke a method of each "MyCustomControl" when the event fires)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask the itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator for this.  See [here](http://blog.nostatic.org/2007/12/wpf-listview-getting-clicked-item.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks David. Your comment led me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980120/finding-control-within-wpf-itemscontrol which is exactly what I was after.