# How to check for visibility of Scroll Bars?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, datagrid

Is there a property in DataGrid which says if currently the scrollbar is visible or not. I want to use the property to control other System.Windows.Control's visibility.

I have gone through a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987028/how-to-check-if-a-scroll-is-currently-visible-in-wpf-datagrid), but the solution has to deal with code-behind.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a property in DataGrid which says if currently the scrollbar is visible or not. **No  there is not.**

I want to use the property to control other System.Windows.Control's visibility.
**Subclass the DataGid and add your property.**