# OnScrollShow event at DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, onscroll

How to handle scroll showing event at DataGrid?

I tried to find some solutions, but there is no one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `DataGrid` class does not have an `OnScrollShow` event. You can handle `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` for when the scroll changes. If you are more specific about what you are trying to accomplish then perhaps we can suggest how you can try to implement the functionality you desire.

In order to detect if the scroll bar is showing, you can hook into the [`LayoutUpdated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated(v=vs.110).aspx) event and use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987215/77074) to detect which scrollbars are visible:

```
ScrollViewer scrollview = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(dataGrid);
Visibility verticalVisibility = scrollview.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
Visibility horizontalVisibility = scrollview.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Okay, I understand that. But, I don't know how can I detect when vertical scroll bar is show.

Comment: Do you merely want to check whether the vertical bar is shown at a point in time?

Comment: I don't want to check, I want to handle vertical scrollbar show event, for example, when I resize the window.