# get ItemsControl in ItemCollection CollectionChanged event 

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, itemscollection

my itemscontrol :

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl"  Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlStyle}" />

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" x:Key="ItemsControlStyle">
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ItemsControlDataItem}"></Setter>
 </Style>

 <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsControlDataItem" >
      <Ellipse Width="45" Height="45"></Ellipse>
 </DataTemplate>
```

iv'e hooked an event to see when the underlying collection as changed :

```
 ((INotifyCollectionChanged)MyItemsControl.Items).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ClientWindow_CollectionChanged);
```

the first thing i need is a way to extract the ItemsControl which owns this ItemCollection

the second thing is to traverse all the data items as their DataTemplate , i.e. as Ellipse 
since i wan't to perform some Transformation on them .

```
   void ClientWindow_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        // here i need to traverse and make my change , how do i extract the ellipse items  
        // how do i get the itemsControl associated with the ItemCollection which triggered this event                
            ItemCollection collection = sender as ItemCollection ;
            foreach (object item in collection)
            {
                //  here i would need the ellipse that the object represents 
                // EDIT : i'm guessing this is how i would get the ellipse    
                // but how would i get the itemsControl ?
                var ellipse = _itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item ) as Ellipse;
            }                    
   }
```

so just to clarify i wan't to traverse the collection and extract the underlying type assigned through the datatemplate .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980120/finding-control-within-wpf-itemscontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ellipse by calling the following code:

```
//  here i would need the ellipse that the object represents 
var container = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
var ellipse = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0);
```

Comment: in this case i only get the collection of checkers each item 
is a checker , and is the DataContext of the Ellipse item i'm trying 
to reference .

Comment: understand that i don't even hold a reference to the ItemsControl itself in this case ,
could you think of a way of referencing the items control 
from the ItemCollection ?

Comment: @eranotzer you'll have to reference MyItemsControl in the code behind, if you have multiple itemscontrols you'll have to keep a mapping of those and compare collection to each of them to ItemControl.Items.

Comment: Unfortunately ItemCollection does not expose it's reference to it's parent control.