# WPF: Does a ListBox throw an event when the content of the ItemsSource changes?

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBox` with its `ItemSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

I have an attached behavior activated in this `ListBox`. This attached behavior hooks into the change event for the `ItemsSource` property. When this event is fired it checks if the new `ItemsSource` value is of type `INotifyCollectionChanged` and if so, it hooks into its `CollectionChanged` event as well.

But when this event is fired, I don't have access to the `ListBox` anymore, just to the `ObservableCollection`.

Is there an event in the `ListBox` that fires, when the content of its `ItemsSource` is changed? So that I have access to the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there is no such event, However, we can use the `Items` property to get around that.

First of all, we will need to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `Items` property:

`((INotifyCollectionChanged)listBox.Items).CollectionChanged += Handler`

Now we have access to the `ItemCollection`:

```
void Handler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   var items = (ItemCollection)sender; 
}
```

As an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829513/get-itemscontrol-in-itemcollection-collectionchanged-event) question suggests, there is no public accessor for the parent `ItemsControl` of the `ItemCollection`. However, [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,56f4e535f8cbb100) piece of reference source shows us that the framework has it in the form of [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ItemCollection.cs,3584e6fff84542bb) field and [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemCollection.cs,7142e0d02c234cb2) convenient property. Now we just have to get reference to it.
You can speed things up by [using delegates](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/) (obviously you would cache them as static fields, below code is for demonstration purposes).

```
var getterMethodInfo = typeof(ItemCollection).GetProperty("ModelParent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetGetMethod(true);
var getterDelegate = (Func<ItemCollection, DependencyObject>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<ItemCollection, DependencyObject>), getterMethodInfo);

var listBox = (ListBox)getterDelegate(items);
```

Comment: Thank you.

For everyone trying that, be sure to hook into the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ListBox`s `ItemsCollection`, not into the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection` you bind the `ItemsSource` to.