# How can I get the objects of the ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to fetch the objects from a ListBox, but ListBox.Items only returns Strings, then I want to check if the item is being focused by a mouse cursor, how can I do this?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: The Items collection contains the elements passed to the ItemsSource property of the ListBox. Either add ListBoxItem explicitly, or use the ListBox's ItemContainerGenerator to get the ListBoxItem container for a string item.

Comment: Uhh, can you show me an example of this in action? Whatever you just said went right over my head and I don't know how to put it in action, a snippet of code to see how it is written would be welcome :).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/ms750552(v=vs.90)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/984862/1136211

Comment: I understand now, this line has been enough to solve my entire issue: item = CType((mySender.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myVar)), ListBoxItem), if you put your comment as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of editing a solution into the question, better write an answer. It's ok to answers your own question.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Post as text and format as code.

Comment: @Mary I'm still new to this platform so I'm learning how to best post my code here, I realize now that it would have been better to put it as text. The question has been answered by Clemens earlier, so going forward I am going to put in only text for my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clemens helped me reach the solution below:

**Solution:**

item = CType((mySender.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(myVar)), ListBoxItem)

Where **mySender** is your ListBox and **myVar** is your Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a handler, which iterates through `ListBox` items:

```
Private Sub ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles listBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

    Dim mySender As ListBox = sender
    Dim item As ListBoxItem

    For Each item In mySender.Items

        If item.IsFocused Then
            MsgBox(item.ToString)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

You can add items like they are (`Strings` in example):

```
Private Sub OnWindowLoad(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    listBox.Items.Add("Item1")
    listBox.Items.Add("Item2")
    listBox.Items.Add("Item3")

End Sub
```

or like `ListBoxItems`:

```
Private Sub OnWindowLoad(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    listBox.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With { .Content = "Item1" })
    listBox.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With { .Content = "Item2" })
    listBox.Items.Add(New ListBoxItem With { .Content = "Item3" })

End Sub
```

In first way (when adding strings as they are) - handler will throw exception about fail to cast `String` to `ListBoxItem`, because you explicitly declare `Dim item As ListBoxItem`. In second way - there wouldn't be cast exception, because you add not Strings, but `ListBoxItem` with `.Content` of `String`.

Obviously you can declare it `Dim item As String` to make things work, but String wouldn't have `IsFocused` property, which you use to show message box.

Even if you set array or list of strings as `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` - it would cause exception too. But array or list of `ListBoxItems`, setted as `ItemsSource` would work in your handler well.

So answer is that `mySender.Items` isn't collection of `ListBoxItem`s, to which you trying to cast and iterate. You should redefine your ItemsSource to be a collection of ListBoxItems or change type of iterated items from `Dim item As ListBoxItem` to `Dim item As String` and lose `IsFocused` property.

You can also use just `SelectedItem` without iterating and checking for `IsFocused` and use safe cast with `TryCast` and check whether item is ListBoxItem or just use `SelectedItem` itself and at end call ToString on it:

```
Dim mySender As ListBox = sender
Dim item

If mySender.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
    item = TryCast(mySender.SelectedItem, ListBoxItem)

    If item Is Nothing Then
        item = mySender.SelectedItem
    End If

    MsgBox(item.ToString)

End If
```

Comment: Or use the ListBox's ItemContainerGenerator to get the ListBoxItem container of an integer item.